# Passing URL variable via $_GET to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, get

I have a PHP page with the following URL:

```
http://xyz.com/dev/gallery.php?k=1&s=35
```

The following Javascript file is included on the PHP page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/some-js-file.php"></script>
```

The some-js-file.php needs to be filled dynamically using PHP:

```
jQuery(function($){$.supersized({

<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id=".$_GET['s']." ORDER BY pos ASC"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
    while($rs = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    ...do some output here...
    }
?>

});
});
```

For some reason, $_GET['s'] is empty. Any ideas why? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the parameter to the JavaScript file as well:

```
<script src="js/some-js-file.php?s=<?php print $_GET['s']; ?>"></script>
```

**N.B.:** Please pay attention to [Quentin's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382905/passing-url-variable-via-get-to-javascript/19382952#comment28725238_19382952) and make sure that you use the approach securely.

Comment: **Danger**: This is vulnerable to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks. Never insert external data into HTML without sanitising it! Add `htmlspecialchars` to fix it.